# Filter list from a list of lists

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

In Haskell, I have the following problem:

```
toBin :: Integer -> Integer
toBin n = read (showIntAtBase 2 intToDigit n "")

-- λ> toBin 558745840
-- 100001010011011100100011110000
-- (0.01 secs, 117,680 bytes)

digitosAgrupados :: Integer -> [[Integer]]
digitosAgrupados n = group [read[d] | d <- show n]

-- λ> digitosAgrupados (toBin 558745840)
-- [[1],[0,0,0,0],[1],[0],[1],[0,0],[1,1],[0],[1,1,1],[0,0],[1],[0,0,0],[1,1,1,1],[0,0,0,0]]
-- (0.01 secs, 288,624 bytes)
```

---

I have to drop the list of ones that cames from `digitosAgrupados n`

```
[[1],[0,0,0,0],[1],[0],[1],[0,0],[1,1],[0],[1,1,1],[0,0],[1],[0,0,0],[1,1,1,1],[0,0,0,0]] --> [[0,0,0,0],[0],[0,0],[0],[0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]
```

That is to say, from a list made up of lists of ones and zeros, to extract the lists of some ones.I have tried `filter (all odd) xss`

Comment: What is the expected output to that? All the lists that contain ones in them?

Comment: Yes, it is a binary list

Comment: Only has list of ones and zeros @RoadRunner

Comment: `filter (all odd) xss`? Or do you want `map (filter odd) xss`?

Comment: `filter (all odd) xss`  @DanRobertson

Comment: What should you get if `xss=[[0,0],[0,1],[1,1]]`?

Comment: I couldn't get this because the list came from `group` so `xss = [[0,0,0], [1,1,1]]`  I have the list of digits binary and apply `group` to get xss

Comment: I have changed for explained better @DanRobertson

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let’s first state the problem:

> input is a list of lists. Each of those lists is nonempty and consists of either all 0 or all 1. The output should be those lists which are all 0.

So we want to filter out the lists which are all 0. The simplest way to do this is:

```
filter (all (==0)) xss
```

This requires us to examine all elements of the lists of 0’s and only a single element of the lists of 1’s. We can do better by examining the first element only:

```
filter ((==0) . head) xss
```

Now our assumption is that no list is empty. We can be robust to that by also removing empty lists:

```
filter (\xs -> not (null xs) && head xs == 0) xss
```